# Why Win32 doesn't have zombie thread issue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, posix

Just know if we call the pthread_create with default `pthread_attr_t`, then `Posix` will keep the exited thread information for other thread to query it, there is zombie thread leak if we didn't call `pthread_join`.

But as I know, on `Windows` platform, you doesn't need to call `WaitForSingleObject` or `GetExitCodeThread` after an thread existed.

So how `Win32` handle zombie thread issue, will there resource leak?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Windows, threads are kernel objects that are referenced from user mode by `HANDLE`s. One property of a kernel object is that it ["remains in memory as long as at least one object handle exists."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you do not call `CloseHandle` on your thread handle(s), you will leak the kernel object.